# Java. Generate swt.table from ArrayList of abstract collection

Tags: java, arraylist

Good day.

My situation is following:

I've got some database entities classes (`Auto`, `Driver`, `Bill`, etc) with some their fields. I can get ArrayList of them from my database - `ArrayList<Auto>`, `ArrayList<Driver>`, etc.

Now i want to be able to generate swt table from any collection i have. 
So, in my dreams it's something like one common method for all classes collections.

```
public class TableGenerator{
    public Table generate(Shell shell, ArrayList<? extends IDBEntity> instance){
        //swt.table creation
        //passing data into this table
    }
}
```

So. question is "Can i do this, so if i can how to do this? " and "Is this way worth to implement or may be should i make different methods for different classes?".

Thank you for any advices and suggestions.

Comment: You want the fields of any subclass of `IDBEntity` to show up as a columns in the table?

Answer (score 1):

one way to achieve this is to use the `Visitor Pattern`.

1. Create a `Visitor` interface:

   ```
   public interface DBEntityVisitor {
     void visit(Auto pAuto);
     void visit(Driver pDriver);
     void visit(Bill pBill);  
   }
   ```
2. Go to the `IDBEntity` interface and add the method:

   ```
    void accept(DBEntityVisitor pDBEntityVisitor);
   ```
3. Now go to the concrete classes `Auto`, `Bill` and `Driver` and implement the `accept` method:

   ```
     @Override
     public void accept(DBEntityVisitor pDBEntityVisitor) {
        pDBEntityVisitor.visit(this);
     }
   ```
4. in your `TableGenerator`:

   ```
      public Table generate(Shell shell, ArrayList<IDBEntity> instance){
        DBEntityVisitor lVisitor = new DBEntityVisitor() {

        @Override
        public void visit(Auto pAuto) {
           System.out.println("I am a car");
        }

        @Override
        public void visit(Driver pDriver) {
           System.out.println("I am a driver");        
        }

        @Override
        public void visit(Bill pBill) {
           System.out.println("I am a bill");
        }
     };
     for(IDBEntity lInstance : instance){
       lInstance.accept(lVisitor);
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: whoa, that's nice, i'll try it

Comment: is visitor accepting it foreach cycle used because you thought that ArrayList holds different dbEntities?

Comment: yes I thought it holds different objects that implements IDBEntity. Nevertheless if the list contains only Auto's only the visit method of Auto would be executed n times.

Comment: I also need to generate  headers for tables. So, i think i should refuse to use this cycle and call 'accept' method once. Anyway, your code is awesome and i should thank you again :)

Comment: yes I know that's the reason for my solution. You can add the individual stuff in the visitor method of each concrete class. From my point of view it's not necessary to do it with json and add a json library.

Comment: just understood that i can't do anything without this cycle, and now i don't know where to put header generation code :) Is it good practice having two visitors: first for preparation, second for directly action?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it very dynamic you can use the introspection given by [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) by making your arrays JSON arrays and objects JSON objects.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

List<IDBEntity> l = new ArrayList<>();
l.add(new Auto());
l.add(new Driver());
l.add(new Bill());

String json = gson.toJson(l);
// Just to view if data is alright.
System.out.println(json)

JsonArray a = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonArray();

// Iterate array
for (JsonElement o: a) {
    // Iterate fields and values of each object
    for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> e: ((JsonObject) o).entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(e.getKey());
        System.out.println(e.getValue());
    }
}
```

Now inspect your array of objects, check their properties to add columns, then run over each object and add the values of the properties it has to the columns.

Comment: Wow, thank you. I've never used json in java, so i need a little bit time to implement your suggestion:)

Comment: It's always nice to have a JSON version of ones data at hand I think :-)

Comment: Yeah, not arguing at all, but in my occasion, time is money :)

Comment: Sometimes spending time, save you time later.